# extract nth number in a string using bash commands

Tags: bash, sed

running the following command I get 0271, is there a way to get 0, 27, and 1 separately?

```
echo '!    ibrav = 0, nat = 27, ntyp = 1' | sed -r 's/[^1-9]*//g'
```

Comment: Why `1-9` instead of `0-9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` instead of `sed`. The `-o` option prints just the matching parts, and each match is on a separate line.

```
echo '!    ibrav = 0, nat = 27, ntyp = 1' | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
0
27
1
```

Comment: grep still doesn't let me access the numbers separately to assign them to different variables

Comment: It puts them each on a different line of the output.

Comment: yes, how do I assign each to different variables?

Comment: You can put them in an array: `arrayvar=($(echo '!    ibrav = 0, nat = 27, ntyp = 1' | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'))`

Comment: why it doesn't work in a make file like this:  `$(eval NUM := ($(shell echo $(VAR) | grep -E -o '[0-9]+')))`

Comment: `make` doesn't have arrays.

Comment: You're trying to mix bash and make syntax.

Comment: The question said nothing about `make`, it was about `bash`.

Comment: yes, I want to use it in a make environment what would be a good approach for that?

Comment: You might get some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983726/variables-in-makefiles-how-to-use-arrays

Comment: @Amir: (1) If you want the result in three separate variables instead of an array, use `grep -o` together with the `read` command. (2) If you have new requirements which are not present in your original question, please ask a new question and don't discuss new problems in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach to work in both bash and make environments. assuming;

```
VAR='!    ibrav = 0, nat = 27, ntyp = 1'
```

bash:

```
echo $(VAR) | grep -Po '(nat = \d+)')
```

make:

```
$(eval NUM := $(shell echo $(VAR) | grep -Po '(nat = \d+)'))
```